# Parse xml document - comment lines also identified as nodes

Tags: xml, delphi, txmldocument

When processing an XML document, the 'comment' lines (starting with `<!--`) are also parsed as nodes. Example of xml:

```
<Message xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <!-- Element comment -->
    <id extension="test"/>
</Message>
```

Code to parse:

```
  XmlDoc := TXmlDocument.Create(nil);
  XmlDoc.LoadFromFile('C:\test.xml');

  msgNode := XMLDoc.ChildNodes.FindNode('Message');

  NofChildren := 0;
  for i := 0 to msgNode.ChildNodes.Count-1 do begin
    Inc(NofChildren);
    tmpNode := msgNode.ChildNodes[i];
    // for comment line: tmpNode.LocalName = ''
  end;
```

Previous code results in `NofChildren = 2`.

Is there a way to avoid the comment lines being treated/parsed as actual XML data?

Tested with RAD Studio 10.2.3 and 11.3.

Comment: Check the type of each node.

Comment: This is expected behavior. Comments are still nodes, they are part of the DOM tree. When processing nodes, pay attention to each node's [`NodeType`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Xml.XMLIntf.IXMLNode.NodeType) as there may be other nodes you're not interested in, like processing instructions, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first solution consisted of checking the `LocalName` property.

However I changed this to checking if `NodeType <> ntComment`.

Note: this question was to ensure there wasn't any possibility to filter out the comments on parsing the XML document.